# String getting null while converting Date to String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I am facing an issue while converting Date to String, for UILabel

Sample code:

```
//format date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *artDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:item.pubDate];


    NSLog(@"%@", item.pubDate); // Output going right Fri, 21 Jun 2013 17:45:20 +0300

    NSLog(@"%@", artDate); // string getting null
```

While it converting to string from NSDate format, I am always getting null here. If I'll put instead of my var item.pubDate current date [NSDate date] all working fine

Any help appreciated

Comment: Possibly see if this solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742713/how-to-convert-the-date-string-into-string-yyyy-mm-dd-while-doing-so-i-getti?rq=1

Comment: I tried your exact code except with [NSDate date] and it worked fine. Is something different about item.pubDate?

Comment: @rocky ok, I found the problem. I am parsing XML and fethicng date from there, so I put type of var NSDate instead of string. I changed in my model file NSString and now it's ok

Comment: samo, samo, samo, samo...  Boring, boring, boring, boring, boring...

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the problem. I am parsing XML and fethicng date from there, so I put type of var NSDate instead of string. I changed in my model file NSString and now it's ok